# OSGi web console not showing in WildFly-8.2.0.Final

Tags: jboss, osgi, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have integrated arcivanov/jbosgi at 2.3.0.Final · GitHub to WildFly-8.2.0.Final. Then server started well and displayed OSGi activation logs. But the OSGi tab to manage bundles from web console is missing.

I have installed the Felix Web Console.
The console is then accessible on: http://localhost:8080/system/console

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Felix web console will only work with an OSGi http service (see chapter 102 of the OSGi specification). I guess the OSGi bridge you are using does not provide it, or doesn't provide it on the HTTP port you are using.

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I am able to install Felix web console. But not WildFly not showing OSGi tab, may be that is not supported.

Comment: AFAIK, JBoss removed the OSGi support form Wildfly. That's most likely why you don't get any OSGi tabs there.